# Sequelize - Order By before Include

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a main table where I join other tables based in an id.

I use include with this other tables and everything works fine.

Problem is that I want to order the main table by create_at before doing any join/includes.

I need this because the db runs out of sorting memory.

Comment: Can you add model definitions and associations? And also a query itself

Comment: @Anatoly many thanks for the tip can you send me some reference docs.

Comment: About what exactly?